# Importing data from an XML file into R

Tags: xml, r, data-import

I want to import an XML file from polarpersonaltrainer.com that stores heartrate data into a R data.frame.
Is there a package that makes importing XML easy or do I have to write my own parser?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Use the `XML` package. There's a function called xmlToDataFrame which will make your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [RSXML](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/) useful. It's also in [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).

Comment: No, RSXML is precursors to XML, and only on Omegahat. You really want XML as Shane said.

Comment: Why does the XML entry on CRAN link to the RSXML website? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/